# Check whether an array is empty without using a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, isset

Is there any function available in PHP to check whether an array is empty or how can I do this without using loop?

For example: `$b = array('key1' => '', 'key2' => '', 'key3' => '', 'key4' => '');`

How can I check array $b contains empty values without using a loop?

Comment: i have tried with count and sizeof functions, its returning only indexes not values.

Comment: Cletus is right when he says that you'll be looping no matter what, but I am kind of wondering why you want to avoid looping. Is there a reason other than curiosity?

Comment: i have large number of values through multi dimensional array. so i thought it would a better if i reject using loops ...

Comment: Why are you storing empty values? And if you have lots of those in an array with only a couple of non-empty ones, maybe you should think about your data structure. It doesn’t seem optimal.

Comment: sorry when i typed this answer it only had one line "how to detect if an array is empty...."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple:

```
function allEmpty($array)
{
    return empty(array_filter($array)); // (PHP < 5.3) or
    $array = array_filter($array); return empty($array); // (PHP >= 5.3) or just
    return array_filter($array) === array();
}

function someEmpty($array)
{
    return ($array !== array_filter($array));
}
```

Comment: I guess because technically it's still looping, but it might be arguably better than writing your own loop.

Comment: +1 to counter-act.  Downvoting without reason is stupid, guys.

Comment: @deceze: No matter what, it's the best answer so far, at least IMHO.

Comment: @eyze: I think so too. I actually posted the exact same thing, but removed it as duplicate.

Comment: Well, it IS still looping, and if your array happens to contain numbers it will conclude that all elements containing 0 are empty as well, which may be a source of error. I don't think this is the best answer so far, because it suggests that empty() does not use loops. Did not down vote it, though.

Comment: `empty()` does not use loops, `array_filter()` does. You can change your definition of "empty" by supplying a custom comparison function to `array_filter`.

Comment: @Banang: I can think of serialize() but it also loops. A solution for this will always loop, like you said before. But I guess we can agree that we don't have to take all **literally**, I think what paulrajj wants is a solution where **he** doesn't need to code the loop, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: @paulrajj: That's because you didn't mentioned it was a multidimensional array, I'll patch up the code in a bit.

Comment: @paulrajj: I can't come up with a solution for multidimensional arrays that doesn't uses loops (so little time!), try messing around with the code provided and array_map() or array_walk(). Sorry. =\

Comment: For `someEmpty()`, why not just say `return $array !== array_filter($array);` and be done with it? Why create an unnecessary `if` block just to return a boolean value?

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Yeah, it's my coding style, but you can surely do that.

Comment: It's a coding style that annoys the hell out of me, but fair enough.

Comment: The 1st example does **not work**. You can't use a **function return value in write context** (at least not with PHP 5.3.1).

Comment: @kaiser: That's true since PHP 5.3 I think. The fix is straightforward tho.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you use a loop or some array function, you're still looping through the array so keep it simple and just loop through the array:

```
function isEmpty($arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Depending on what you want to define as empty, you may want to only check for empty strings:

```
function isEmpty($arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($v === '') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check for empty strings `''` you can use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array)

```
if(!in_array('', $array)) echo 'array doesn’t contain empty strings';
if(in_array('', $array)) echo 'array does contain at least one empty string';
```

you might also want to try [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) with an empty callback method, and compare that to an empty array (or use `empty()`):

```
if(empty(array_filter($array))) echo 'array only contains values evaluating to false';
```

Comment: what was the downvote for? i edited my question to show better what i meant

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no.

If you don't want to do a literal foreach/for/while, you can use [array_walk](http://us.php.net/array_walk).

Answer (score 1):

If that is the specific array you want to check (ie: it only has key=>values and empty is always key=>'') ...

```
$b = array('key1' => '', 'key2' => '', 'key3' => '', 'key4' => '');
$temp = array_flip($b);
if(count($temp) === 1 && empty($temp[0])){
    echo 'empty';
}
```

Otherwise you are going to have to use a loop... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I usually check it by using following condition:

```
if(is_array($array) and count($array)) {
 //  ... code here ...
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
if(!array_filter($array)){
  //Is empty
}
else
{
  //Is not empty
}
```

do the work.